# Python 2D Array - Get Value by Key

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose it is the following structure given:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# Constants for all available difficulty types.
SIMPLE = 1
MEDIUM = 2
DIFFICULT = 3

# Names for all available difficulty types.
DIFFICULTIES = (
    (SIMPLE, _("simple")),
    (MEDIUM, _("medium")),
    (DIFFICULT, _("difficult")),
)
```

How do you get the string value, if a constant is given?

A loop is easy to program, but is there a shorter python-like way with a single expression?

The expression

> DIFFICULTIES[SIMPLE][1]

returns the string "medium". What is obviously wrong.

Comment: Are you searching for [`dictionary`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: What are the underscores doing in there? `_("simple")` doesn't look like syntactically valid Python to me.

Comment: I'd guess that the underscores were there as references to gettext's `_` function for internationalization (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html?highlight=gettext#gettext.install)).

Comment: @DSM: I see, interesting. It seems a bit unpythonic though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Of course you can use a dict, but the array is given.

So exchange it.  (I'm assuming you kept the receipt..)

```
>>> dict(DIFFICULTIES)
{1: 'simple', 2: 'medium', 3: 'difficult'}
>>> d = dict(DIFFICULTIES)
>>> d[MEDIUM]
'medium'
```

Searching through an unsorted tuple for something simply isn't the right way to go about things.  I suppose you could do

```
>>> next(v for k,v in DIFFICULTIES if k == MEDIUM)
'medium'
```

if you wanted to avoid a for loop with a colon, but that's a little silly.

Comment: Great, thanks! I've searched this expression dict(DIFFICULTIES)[SIMPLE]

Answer (score 1):

it just because you specified a tuple, an indexing starting from 0, you either need to switch to dictionary or modify your constants with correct values:

```
DIFFICULTIES = {SIMPLE: "simple", MEDIUM: "medium", DIFFICULT: "difficult"}
```

OR:

```
SIMPLE, MEDIUM, DIFFICULT = range(3)
```

Comment: Then what about second suggestion about const chg

Comment: Would be a possibility, but I do not know how it impacts on the whole project, because other dependencies exist. I will solve it with a loop. Thought there would be a shorter solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary:

```
SIMPLE, MEDIUM, DIFFICULT = range(3)
DIFFICULTIES = {
    SIMPLE: _("simple"),
    MEDIUM: _("medium"),
    DIFFICULT: _("difficult")
}
DIFFICULTIES[SIMPLE] # will return "simple"
```

Comment: NameError: name '_' is not defined

Comment: I just copied the code from the question. Guess those `_` and the brackets gotta go

Comment: Then the only thing you can do is to go with Artsiom Rudzenka's answer (let the index start at 0, not at 1)